# Automatically fill out a large dataset based on number ranges

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a large table (150k+ rows) in Excel that I am trying to fill out based on some preliminary available information. I will post my current table structure and desired results below, but as an outline of my project: I have three primary columns of data, with a fourth that may be useful depending on approaches recommended. The existing data identifies a column for a Group's ID, a column for their Start Year, a column for their End Year, and a column for the total years active (derived simply from End Year minus Start Year). The existing data range is derived from rows of individual member records, but those IDs have been removed. Using this data my ultimate goal is to find the average Group size per year. I have a number of tools to approach this, and it will ultimately end up in MySQL. Until then, I plan to try to pull a number of statistics from it, but again, the **goal is to find the average Group size (size based off of count of members in that Group) on a year by year basis** to be able to plot average size for the past 100 years. My data is as follows:

```
  |    A   |      B       |     C      |       D        |
  |   ID   |  Start Year  |  End Year  |  Years Active  |
1 |   101  |     1967     |     1975   |       7        |
2 |   101  |     1957     |     1965   |       7        |
3 |   125  |     1960     |     1975   |       15       |
4 |   136  |     1905     |     1908   |       3        |
5 |   222  |     1964     |     1975   |       7        |
6 |   121  |     1964     |     1975   |       7        |
7 |   102  |     1952     |     1975   |       7        |
8 |   306  |     1952     |     1975   |       7        |
9 |   306  |     1972     |     1975   |       7        |
10|   172  |     1967     |     1971   |       4        |
11|   411  |     1947     |     1951   |       4        |
12|   411  |     1946     |     1950   |       4        |
13|   411  |     1946     |     1950   |       4        |
14|   411  |     1946     |     1950   |       4        |
15|   411  |     1946     |     1950   |       4        |
16|   172  |     1945     |     1949   |       4        |
17|   172  |     1963     |     1967   |       4        |
18|   301  |     1948     |     1952   |       4        |
19|   301  |     1948     |     1952   |       4        |
20|   301  |     1972     |     1976   |       4        |
```

The above representation is how my data is currently in Excel, down to 150,784 rows. My current path has me thinking I need to be able to explode out the date between the Start Year and the End Year to know which member was active in which year, and for which Group ID. From that, I know I can manage the long way of doing some Subtotaling to figure out what I need, but I wonder if someone can think of a formula schema or macro to make this a slightly less impossible task. I feel I am getting lost in the multi-axis approach this seems that it needs to avoid doing it for each year (1899-2015 for the full data set). I hope that I am missing the trees while staring at the forest and there is an obvious solution/approach to take, but any advise or help you can provide would in all sincerity be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance to those that contribute!

Comment: _I will post my current table structure and desired results below_ where is the desired results structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps expand out your data, say with years in row1 (starting with `1899` in E1) and in E2 etc:

```
=--AND($B2<=E$1,E$1<=$C2)
```

It would result in a very large matrix but one that might make further processing relatively easy. Convert the formulae resulting in binary output to values and processing times should not be much of an issue.

[image]

Comment: That is along the lines that I was thinking of going, unless a more elegant solution can be found. I am trying to replicate your results but am having some difficulty, currently working on it. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: I agree in removing the 0 values as my goal is a Count anyway. I seemed to have to redo my headings to values to get your formula to return valid results, which is looks like it does. Currently crunching all 18 million+ cells now.